# Navigation with back jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of anchor tags in a page, on click of that anchor tag it will navigate to another page based on href which is already defined.

Now after navigating to second page, I will have couple of anchor tags, again on click of each anchor tag it will navigate to corresponding href page.

Now on click of back button, it should navigate to previous page i.e. second page again on click of back button it will navigate to first page.

Can anyone help me out how to achieve this in generic way, so that in case if there are three navigations instead of two also it should work.

This is what I have tried.

Header:

```
<button id='back'>Back</button>
```

Page 1:

```
<ul class='list'>
<li><a href='/page1/anchor1'>Page 1 Anchor1</a></li>
<li><a href='/page1/anchor2'>Page 1 Anchor2</a></li>
<li><a href='/page1/anchor3'>Page 1 Anchor3</a></li>
<li><a href='/page1/anchor4'>Page 1 Anchor4</a></li>
<li><a href='/page1/anchor5'>Page 1 Anchor5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Page 2:

```
<ul class='list'>
<li><a href='/page2/anchor1'>Page 2 Anchor1</a></li>
<li><a href='/page2/anchor2'>Page 2 Anchor2</a></li>
<li><a href='/page2/anchor3'>Page 2 Anchor3</a></li>
<li><a href='/page2/anchor4'>Page 2 Anchor4</a></li>
<li><a href='/page2/anchor5'>Page 2 Anchor5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Page 3:

```
<ul class='final'>
<li>Page 3 Anchor1</li>
<li>Page 3 Anchor2</li>
<li>Page 3 Anchor3</li>
<li>Page 3 Anchor4</li>
<li>Page 3 Anchor5</li>
</ul>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function(){
            // Having the array of href
            var rList = $('.list li a');
            purl = [];
            var aurl = [];
            for(var i=0;i<rList.length;i++){
                arl = rList[i].href;
                purl.push(aurl);
            }

        },500);

        $("#back").click(function(){


        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History

```
$("#back").click(function(){
        history.back();
    });
```